# codeigniter how can I manage objects from mother controller to two child controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

---

I have created 2 controllers for paging and 1 controller for model and one model for database. and 2 controller extends to other controller. like this

```
class MY_Data extends CI_Controller{
     public $layout;
     public $xe_member;
     public $member_srl;
     public $is_logged_in = FALSE;
     public $is_registerd = false;
     public $director = array();
     public $fighters = array();
     public $logged;

    function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('member_login');
         $this->load->model('db_log');
         $this->layout = 'include/template';
    }
    function load_data(){
         $this->xe_member = $this->member_login->member_check();
         $this->member_srl = $this->xe_member['member_srl'];
         $this->is_logged_in = $this->xe_member['is_logged'];
         $this->is_registerd = $this->member_login->register_check
                              ($this->member_srl);
         if($this->is_registerd){
            $this->director = $this->db->where('member_srl', $this->member_srl)->
            limit(1)->get('fc_directors')->row();
            $this->fighters = $this->db->where('member_srl', $this->member_srl)->
            get('fc_fighters')->result();
         }
     }
}
```

login

```
class Login extends MY_Data {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('member_login');
}
public function index()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
        $data['PHPSESSID'] = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    }else {
        $this->load->view('include/template', 'login_error');
        die();
    }
    $this->load_data();

    if($this->is_logged_in)
    {

        if ($this->is_registerd) {

            $data['log'] = $this->db_log->read_all_log();
            $data['main_contents'] = 'main/main';
            $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
        } else {

            redirect('registration');
        }
    } else {
        $data['main_contents'] = 'login_error';
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
    }

}
```

and main

```
class Main extends MY_Data {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
function index(){
    if(!$this->logged){
        $data['main_contents'] = 'login/login_button';
        $this->load->view($this->layout,$data);
    }else {
        $data['main_contents'] = 'main/main';
        $this->load->view($this->layout,$data);             
    }
}
```

I know is not perfect code but...
what I want to do here:
first call login to db_data will pull the db store in objects and main take object to display. but I always got null from mother controller when use main.

I simply use controller object to other controller.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the first line in function index in Main be

```
parent::index();
```

I guess you want to extend the index function you have in class Login.

Now index in the parent class is not executed and the following line is not called:

```
$this->load_data()
```

which contains

```
$this->member_login->member_check();
```

Does that solve your problem?